# Tomcat 6.0.32 error coming while running my application

Tags: tomcat6

I have created a war file of my application using maven.the build was successful.Now i have deployed the same build on my tomcat server.But when i try to access my application i receive the following error message..

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Mandatory TLD element tlib-version missing or empty in TLD /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld 
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:281)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

any one having any clue please update
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that it can't find a valid tlib-version element.

Open /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld ... It probably has a valid `<taglib>` root element, but does it have a `tlib-version` subelement, such as:

```
<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
....
....
</taglib>
```

You can read more about tag library descriptors here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html

Comment: Thanks Lynn,I have checked my struts-html.tld and it contains the <tlibversion></tlibversion> tag.Then also its not working.Have a look from my struts-html.tld   <tlibversion>1.2</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>html</shortname>

Comment: @user1169095 Looks like your tag is called tlibversion, when it should be called tlib-version (don't forget to change the closing tag, too.)

Comment: @user1169095 Did changing tlibversion to tbl-version fix that?

Comment: HI I am also facing the same issue. i have <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version> in my custom tag file but still its giving error. can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your taglib is like below

`<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jsee/web-jsptagLibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">`